# Salesforce REST token as SOAP SessionID

Tags: salesforce

Can I use REST token as SOAP session ID? If so, is that a correct way of doing it? I have an App which consume SOAP and want to give an option to OAuth login to avoid user entering credentials to the App.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm able to get the token back from REST, add it to the SOAP session header, but when I'm trying to make a call (e.g. SalesforceService.describeGlobal()), it throws a weird exception:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll

Additional information: Client found response content type of 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the access token resulting from your OAuth flow and use it in the same place that you'd use a sessionId in the SOAP API (i.e. you'd send it in the SessionHeader header in your soap requests). Remember that you'll need to include API scope when you start the OAuth flow.

Comment: Thanks superfell, but it throws INVALID_SESSION_ID. What should I set for SOAP URL?

Comment: You can get the relevant soap URL from the Id service (make a GET request to the URI returned as the users Id from the OAuth flow)